Can't draw on texture, creates multiple cells
I am following a tutorial and stuck on 5:26
Why I can't draw on textures just like on the video? It creates multiple copies of the same texture all over the plane. My video and project attached:
https://imgur.com/a/hOG0SyL


Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

The only things you do not show in your video are the mesh of your plane and the UV map. Since you are using the UV output of the Texture Coordinate node and have set the Extrapolation mode of the Image Texture to Repeat, I guess you have a subdivided plane there and you have either reset the UVs or deleted the UV map and added a new one, which also resets the UVs.
If you want the image to fill the whole plane, the geometry and the UVs should look like that, the plane as a whole fills up the UV space and it is subdivided by the individual faces:

But what your UV map most likely looks like is you can only see a single face filling the whole UV map. These are all individual faces, each filling up the area so the texture gets repeated on each of them.

On a simple object like this subdivided plane you can fix this by doing the following: first of all go into Edit Mode and then select all faces with A. Then press U and either choose Unwrap or if you are for example in Top View choose Project From View (Bounds).
In my example the simple Unwrap leads to the image appearing rotated by 90°, you can change that by selecting all UVs in the UV Editor and pressing R 90 or -90 depending on if you need to rotate it clockwise or counter-clockwise of course.
For more complex meshes I would highly recommend you watch tutorials on UV mapping and texturing, because as it seems there is a lack of knowledge regarding these topics. No offense, this is normal for beginners since UV mapping can be quite complex.

Thank you so much, that was the answer. I've selected my plane and pressed U and Unwrap. You have my gratitude, friend!
